# How can I make the player smoothly rotate and return to a collider once it exits it?

Tags: unity, c#

When the player exits the collider area, it slows down then stops. At this point I want the player to start rotating and start moving back inside the colliding area.

The exit and the slow down are working but the rotation is not working and I'm not sure how to make him start moving again slowly to max speed when entering back.

The main goal is to prevent the player to leave the marked colliding area with some slow down and rotation.

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerSpaceshipAreaColliding : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float timeElapsed = 0;
    private float lerpDuration = 3;
    private float startValue = 1;
    private float endValue = 0;
    private float valueToLerp = 0;
    private Animator playerAnimator;
    private bool exitSpaceShipSurroundingArea = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (exitSpaceShipSurroundingArea)
        {
            SlowDown();

            if (playerAnimator.GetFloat("Forward") == 0)
            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Inverse(transform.rotation);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.name == "CrashLandedShipUpDown")
        {
            exitSpaceShipSurroundingArea = false;
            Debug.Log("Entered Spaceship Area !");
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.name == "CrashLandedShipUpDown")
        {
            exitSpaceShipSurroundingArea = true;
            Debug.Log("Exited Spaceship Area !");
        }
    }

    private void SlowDown()
    {
        if (timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
        {
            valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
            playerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
            timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        }
        playerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);

        valueToLerp = 0;
    }
}
```

For the rotation I did:

```
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Inverse(transform.rotation);
```

but it keeps rotating non stop and not slowing smoothly like using Lerp.

[image: The collider area]

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [sine function](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Sin.html) to what I think you want. You could then attach a [rotation lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html) to smooth it out. Here is a script for what this would look like (you have to implement this):

```cs
Quaternion a;//the start
Quaternion b;//and end point.
float period = 2f;//amount of seconds to rotate back and forth.

void Update()
{
  float cycles = Time.time / period;
  float amplitude = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.PI * 2 * cycles);
  amplitude /= 2;
  amplitude += 0.5f;
  transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(a, b, amplitude);
}
```

Basically, you get the amount of cycles after `period` seconds. Then, you get a value from -1 to 1 (changing based on cycles because our use of sine). We don’t want that because `Quaternion.Slerp` takes a value from 0 to 1 as its third argument, so we divide by two (to get a value from -0.5 to 0.5), then add 0.5 (to get a value from 0 to 1). We the use `Quaternion.Slerp` to rotate between both points based on this 0 to 1 value.

---

- [What is sine used for in programming?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFOi6W7lohk)
- [What is Quaternion.Slerp?](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1557501/understanding-quaternionslerpquaternionrotatetowar.html)